# Recurring Donation option not appearing on Mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal

A client uses PayPal to accept donations. On desktop, their paypal form includes an option for monthly recurring donations. However, on mobile, their form does not include the recurring option.

Is there a way to display the recurring option on mobile that they are missing?

Comment: It's a known defect for PayPal  donation button. PayPal will add this feature later

Comment: @ZhaoSamanta Thank you! I assumed as much, but was curious if anyone has discovered a workaround.

Comment: For donation button, I am afraid there is no workaround. But you can use subscription button to act as a recurring donation , it should work in mobile.

Comment: @ZhaoSamanta Great, I'll recommend that to my client. Thanks for your help!